# Redirecting wordpress urls in a ghost site hosted in Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, iis, url-rewriting, ghost

I recently switched my blog from wordpress to ghost. In order to keep the old wordpress urls working, I added some rewrite rules.

My wordpress site used the following url formats:

- `/blog/year/month/post-title`
- `/blog/index.php/year/month/post-title`

Ghost uses the following url format:

- `/post-title`

Here's my main rewrite rule. It works fine for the pattern without index.php, but with index.php, it redirects to `/index/`.

```
<rule name="wordpress to ghost" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^blog/(index\.php/)?\d+/\d+/([\w\-]+)/?" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

How can I fix this rule to correctly redirect urls with index.php?

Comment: Have been able to give the escaped regex pattern in my answer below a test yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested this with my own installed instance of Ghost on Azure, but I'm not getting the redirect you are. `{R:2}` correctly returns the second grouping (slug name).

However, I do notice that you are not escaping your forward slashes. Try the following:

```
    <rule name="wordpress to ghost" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^blog\/(index\.php\/)?\d+\/\d+\/([\w\-]+)\/?" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: That worked! But I'm still curious why it worked for links without index.php without escaping forward slashes.